# Json - string cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: json, groovy

I am getting the following error when trying to compare a json value (-3) to a list value (-3). The code works for positive json values:

Error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

I have tried converting the values to string, ints, etc. Each time I get the same error.

Json:

```
[
  {
    "Name”:”Delayed”,
    "ID":-3,
    "Ascending":true,
    "LocalDateTime":"2019-06-14T07:00:00+09:00",
    "EpochDateTime":1560463200,
    "Value":10.0,
    "Category":"Very Unlikely",
    "CategoryValue":5,
  }
]
```

Code:

```
for (item in indiceId) {
   GlobalVariable.indice_id = item
   idResponse = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Object Repository/API/itemsAPI/items_location_id'))
   parsedJsonId = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(idResponse.getResponseBodyContent())
   if (parsedJsonId[0].ID == item) {
       KeywordUtil.markPassed(" Items Response by ID: " + parsedJsonId[0].ID  + " Expected: " + item)
   }
   else {
       KeywordUtil.markFailed(" Items Response by ID: " + parsedJsonId[0].ID  + " Expected: " + item)
   }
}
```

Error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: What's `indiceId`?  Which line causes the exception? Can you reproduce it in a way we can run?

Answer (score 1):

```java
parsedJsonId = Integer.parseInt(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(idResponse.getResponseBodyContent()))
```

Comment: I figured it out. My json path was incorrect. Thanks for the help!